# Multiline span-behaving elements

Tags: css, html

I want to display a list of complex, but fixed-size multiline elements, assuming that they will wrap the page line when line end is reached, making them appear by `n` in each row, when 
`n` depends on page width. Something like:

```
Mary had    Mary had    Mary had
a little    a little    a little
LAMB        LAMP        WHISKEY


Mary had
a little
TOO MUCH
```

How should I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`inline-block` spans should do it:

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
#container span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 5em;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
  <span>Mary had a little lamb</span>
  <span>Mary had a little lamb</span>
  <span>Mary had a little lamb</span>
  <span>Mary had a little lamb</span>
  <span>Mary had a little lamb</span>
  <span>Mary had a little lamb</span>
  <span>Mary had a little lamb</span>
  <span>Mary had a little lamb</span>
  <span>Mary had a little lamb</span>
  <span>Mary had a little lamb</span>
  <span>Mary had a little lamb</span>
  <span>Mary had a little lamb</span>
  <span>Mary had a little lamb</span>
  <span>Mary had a little lamb</span>
  <span>Mary had a little lamb</span>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it should be noted that `inline-block` doesn't work in IE6 :-)

Comment: @Andy E: Actually, it does -- but IE6 will only let you set `inline-block` on elements that normally default to `inline`, not on elements that normally default to `block`. I'd remembered that backward for the example, so I've fixed that now. :-)

Comment: @Andy: Thanks -- and thanks for reminding me about the IE6 weirdness!

Comment: Is there a way to wrap long words? Like if I would add one `<span>Mary had a little jumbomambopeekaboolamb</span>`

Comment: @gilhad: Adding `overflow-wrap: break-word;` would do it, [more](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/prevent-long-urls-from-breaking-out-of-container/).

Answer (score 6):

Use a combination of `display: block;` `float:left;` and your desired `width` and `height`.

```
span {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: @T.J. yeah I can relate to that, I wasn't aware inline-block worked on IE6, though ;-)